# Youtube video shut down automatically

Tags: applications, youtube

Im using wifi internet on android mobile. Watching youtube video after few 3-5 minutes the video shutdown and it comes on the main screen of the mobile. Whats the problem how to solve it. Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Does this happen every time you watch a video?

Comment: What's the device model and Android version? Did you watch it on YouTube app, or mobile browser, or 3rd-party app? Did this happen recently?